# Как регулировать очередность функций в casperjs?

Tags: юнит-тесты, парсер, phantomjs, casperjs

При авторизации заполняются поля в диалоговом окне и нажимается кнопка сабмита. Потом делается сохранение страницы в png, чтобы убедиться, что авторизация прошла успешно. Проблема в том, что при авторизации происходит некоторая задержка и в это время срабатывает скрин страницы и не всегда как хотелось бы ПОСЛЕ авторизации, но и часто ДО окончания авторизации. Вот мой код:

```
// authentication
var casper = require('casper').create({
pageSettings: {
    loadImages: false,//The script is much faster when this field is set to false
    userAgent: 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36'
    }
});


var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.start().thenOpen("http://www.3dcontentcentral.com/parts/all-parts-suppliers.aspx", function() {
console.log("Page is opened");
this.capture('BeforeLogin.png');
});

casper.then(function(){
console.log("Login using username and password");
this.evaluate(function(){
    document.getElementById("login-button").click();
    document.getElementById("3dcclogin").value="mylogin";
    document.getElementById("3dccpassword").value="mypass";
    document.getElementById("btn_ucLogin").click();
});
});

casper.then(function(){
 this.wait(1000, function(){
    console.log("Make a screenshot and save it as AfterLogin.png");
    this.capture('AfterLogin.png');
});

});

casper.run();
```

Пробовал задерживать время методом wait() и выставлял большее время, но это не надежно. Методы типа waitForSelector не могу использовать, т.к. селекторов, к которым можно было бы привязать, не нашел. Прошу подсказать, как сделать так, чтобы пока не отработает авторизация, дальнейшие действия не срабатывали, а ждали своей очереди?

Comment: _"селекторов, к которым можно было бы привязать, не нашел"_ - значит плохо искал. Ну что-то же меняется на странице.

Answer (score 1):

Ждать селекторы с помощью waitForSelector - это самое надежное, на мой взгляд. Но если не хотите так, то у фантома есть событие, которое в принципе означает, что страница загрузилась. С ним есть свои проблемы, но вполне может быть, что в вашем случае этот способ подойдет.

Событие это onLoadFinished: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-load-finished.html

В каспере ему соответствует событие http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#load-finished